# Xcode UI Testing: Automatically taking snapshot when predicates fail?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode UI Testing takes automatic screenshots for viewing in the results navigator whenever a test fails, which is greatly helpful. However, that does not include tests that fail because a predicate is failed. Since predicates are often for basic checks (such as if an element exists or not on a current view), that is a huge drawback because a screenshot would be useful in diagnosing what was happening in the app when the test failed.

Does anyone know how to force a screenshot? Does this require integrating the Fastlane Snapshot tool?

Answer (score 10):

On `tearDown` you can check if test failed (that's helpful if you are not discarding screenshots when tests pass.)

```
if let failureCount = testRun?.failureCount, failureCount > 0 {
  takeScreenshot()
}
```

If you are using Xcode 9 already, the `takeScreenshot` function can use the new API (If not, then use the workaround mentioned by the other answer) :

```
let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
let attach = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
add(attach)
```

You can also name the attach and change its lifetime ;)

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/activities_and_attachments/adding_attachments_to_tests_activities_and_issues) for how to use and where to find them (the "Report navigator" in `View > Navigators > Reports`) in more detail.

Comment: Do you have any idea where it saves the snapshot? Like the Fastlane snapshot can I set a path for that? Thanks.

Comment: The attachment can be found under the "Report navigator" (View > Navigators > Reports). Find your scheme's latest build, look under the Tests for failed ones, dig into the tree to find a "Collecting extra data to assist test failure triage" > "Automatic Screenshot" attachment. But your own attachments can also be found in the report, e.g. if I put that code in the Tear Down phase, I can see I "Added attachment named...".

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to integrate Fastlane Snapshot for this. The only trick Snapshot is doing to force screenshot is triggering this code:

```swift
XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .unknown
```

This will not alter UI as described on Snapshot [documentation](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot#how-does-it-work).

Unfortunately this will not work if you're using expectation for your predicate and you put this code into `waitForExpectations(timeout:handler:)` handler closure and I don't know why.

To workaround this you can create your own XCTestObservation handler like this:

```swift
class MockObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
    func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: UInt) {
        XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .unknown
    }
}

XCTestObservationCenter.shared().addTestObserver(MockObserver())
```

You can put this code in either `setUp()` method or specific `test...` method.

The test output is a little weird as it will show "Set device orientation to Unknown" as an error and actual predicate error inside but you will have your screenshot:

[image: Test execution log]

Answer (score 6):

You can override the recordFailure method to capture screenshots on any kinds of failures.

```
override func recordFailure(withDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String, atLine lineNumber: Int, expected: Bool) {
        add(XCTAttachment(screenshot: XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()))
        super.recordFailure(withDescription: description, inFile: filePath, atLine: lineNumber, expected: expected)
}
```